# Human body organs growth graph or data

Tags: data-visualization, dataset

I am looking for a graph or data for relative growth of human body organs, more importantly head size and total body height.

The full data I would like to have—each as a function of time from birth (and preferably until death)—are:

1. Head size, preferably for both male and female,
2. Hand size,
3. Leg size,
4. Cerebrum weight,
5. Body height, and,
6. Body weight.

I have only found the two last ones, but I'd rather have all data from a single study.

Comment: I would appreciate something slightly different : a public data set like (height, weight, sex) for N adults, or (heigth, weight, sex, age) for N individuals, with N big enough. If in you quest you find this, please let me know.

Comment: Look on the [NHANES](http://www.cdc.gov/nchs/nhanes.htm) site, @Elvis, or go to the [CDC](http://www.cdc.gov/growthcharts/).  (Weight, height, head size, and BMI by age up to 20 years are available at the CDC.  Unfortunately, hand size, leg size, and--especially--cerebrum weight will not be available.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on @whuber's comment, there are several sets of data that one could find:

- Different growth curves for infants (weight-for-age; length-for-age, weight-for-recumbent length; head circumference-for-age) and older children (weight-for-stature; weight-for-age; stature-for-age; and BMI-for-age) can be found at the [CDC site](http://www.cdc.gov/growthcharts/percentile_data_files.htm)
- Different ultrasound fetal measurements including head and abdominal circumferences and a couple of bone lengths can be found, e.g, in this [pregnancy site](http://www.baby2see.com/medical/charts.html#Measurement_Standards_Chart)